# How to catch ParamConverter exceptions in Symfony2?

Tags: php, exception, symfony, doctrine-orm, routes

Here is the exception I got:

> No result was found for query although at least one row was expected.

I am basically getting that exception when a user id is not found in database.
Here is what my route looks like:

```
localhost/../user/18
```

and the code in my controller:

```
public function showAction(User $user){
    // .. 
}
```

I know I can use the kernel event exception to handle this, but is there an easier way to catch an exception generated by the ParamConverter?

Comment: What is your use case? In the example you give the end result would be an NotFoundHttpException which would return a 404 - which is what you would expect if the user didn't exist.

What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In some cases it's useful to throw exception manually if object not found. You can tell action skip throw exception if entity not found by adding default value to param.

Example:

```
public function showUser(User $user = null) {
    if (empty($user)) {
        throw new CustomExceptionYouWant();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I didn't think about !
For more coherence with your parameter User $user = null, think about verifying null === $user instead of empty (but empty works good too !).

Answer (score 2):

You can create your user ParamConverter by implementing ParamConverterInterface and inside it, create methods you can use as a custom exception or do other processing.

This a good exemple of what you want to create [Custom ParamConverter](http://whitewashing.de/2013/02/19/extending_symfony2__paramconverter.html)

Comment: I am agree with you, that's one way to do thisbut maybe there is an easier one :D