# Symfony paramconverter object not found no 404

Tags: parameters, symfony

I just discovered the ParamConverter syntax.

Here is what [the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) says :

> ```
> use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
> use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
>
> /**
>  * @Route("/blog/{id}")
>  * @ParamConverter("post", class="SensioBlogBundle:Post")
>  */
> public function showAction(Post $post) {
> }
> ```
>
> Several things happen under the hood:
>
> - ...
> - **If no Post object is found, a 404 Response is generated**;
> - If a Post object is found, a new post request attribute is defined...
> - ...

I tried this exact thing and it works fine if the id is known but if it is not then I get this Symfony error :

> AppBundle\Entity\MyCustomEntity object not found.

Shouldn't I get a 404 Exception, which redirect me to my custom 404 page ?

Additionnaly, I tried what [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20284189/3888000) suggested, but the condition is not even read, and the same exact "object not found" error is shown again.

Is there any other way to get this working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't I get a 404 Exception, which redirect me to my custom 404
>   page ?

Yes, in `prod` environment

In `dev` environment, you have some explanation about the error to help you debugging.

Answer (score 0):

symfony 6 Param Converter & 404's ==> `composer require sensio/framework-extra-bundle`

```
#[Route('/blog/{date}/{slug}/comments/{comment_slug}')]
#[ParamConverter('post', options: ['mapping' => ['date' => 'date', 'slug' => 'slug']])]
#[ParamConverter('comment', options: ['mapping' => ['comment_slug' => 'slug']])]
public function showComment(Post $post, Comment $comment)
{
}
```